# Wrote a function to quantify nulls in each column of data frame, but doesn't drop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, isnull

I'm writing a function to automatically check the quantity of null values per column in a data frame, then if the amount of nulls is less than or equal to 2000, drop the rows containing null values

I've written some code that successfully outputs the text strings to mark which column it has analyzed

```
def drop_na(df,cols):
    for i in cols:

        missing_vals = df[i].isnull().sum()


        if missing_vals <= 2000:
            df = df.dropna(subset=[i])
        print(f'finished checking column  "{i}"')
    print('FINISHED ALL!')
```

I am checking to see if the null containing rows have been dropped with data.isnull().sum() after running the code successfully (where data is the name of my data frame) but the same null counts exist in the columns

I call the function with drop_na(data, data.columns)

Comment: You should use `inplace=True` in `dropna`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are only deleting the rows only inside the function. Doing it inplace solves the problem as in the following code works:

```
def drop_na(data):
    cols = data.cols
    subset = []
    # Determine bad columns, and store them in `subset` list.
    for i in cols:
        missing_vals = df[i].isnull().sum()
        if missing_vals <= 2000:
            subset.append(i)
    # Now remove all bad columns at once, but inplace.
    df.dropna(subset=subset, inplace=True)
    print('FINISHED ALL!')
```

If you don't want to do it inplace, then returning the `df`, and assigning the returned value to a new variable `df2 = drop_na(data)` works. Do not forget to re-index the new dataframe if you need to.